# ¿Se puede trabajar con CodeIgniter 4 en hosting compartido?

Tags: composer, codeigniter-4, framework

Buen dia a todos, estoy empezando en el mundo de CodeIgniter y queria saber que tan bueno es trabajar con codeigniter en hosting compartido de hostgator, ya que el acceso no es totalmente de administrador. Por ejemplo tan solo usar composer para la administración de paquetes y librerías.

Mi reto es crear un pequeño sistema para manejar una base de datos, de una tienda que pueda tener las opciones de pago, pero necesito manejar accesos, autorizaciones, métodos de pago y muchas cosas mas.

Que me pueden comentar los que han tenido experiencia con este framework en hosting compartidos.

Comment: Hola. Por lo general puedes usar Composer en hosting compartido. Lo he usado sin problemas en Bluehost y en InMotion Hosting. En cuanto a Codeigniter, supongo que también podrás configurarlo. Yo logré desplegar una simple aplicación en Symfony en InMotion, aunque recuerdo haber tenido problemas sobre todo con respecto a las versiones, a veces los frameworks requieren versiones de Composer o de PHP que el hosting no tiene instaladas. Revisa simplemente los requerimientos de Codeigniter. Recuerdo que hubo un problema para desplegar la app con deployer pero lo resolví creando un alias o algo así.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.